# Is there a way to launch the GUI application frome command line without Window Desktop application(like GNOME)?

Tags: fedora, x11, putty

I read the on-line document:
[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130535/launch-gui-apps-from-text-mode-tty-without-loading-window-desktop-manager)

I am using Fedora30.

Is it also possible to launch a gui app. on text mode(init 3 state) as on Ubuntu?

I make ~/.xinitrc and put in xterm &

then after command 'startx', freezed small(tiny window on the screen) terminal appeared.

there is no way to exercute any application on this state. I would like to work on text mode while wandering chrome or firefox without getting into init 6.

Comment: Are you sure typing firefox in the terminal then press enter doesn't work?

Comment: It’s Fedora 30.  It runs systemd. There’s no init 3 or init 6 runlevels like in sysv, really, just different boot targets. What exactly are you trying to do?  Runlevel 3 is the equivalent of multi-user.target and runlevel 6 is graphical.target.  Ubuntu’s runlevels don’t match up with Fedora’s due to legacy differences, but for both, their systemd targets are the same.